# Why faster to apply each function separately to image collection in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, profiler

In my batch image processing workflow in GEE I have separate functions for each step, e.g. one function masks clouds, the next does classification, etc. I compared two approaches to apply my functions: **1)** `.map()` each function across the collection, and **2)** a single `.map()` that calls a master function, which applies each function to each image individually. I ran each with the profiler, and found **1** was faster. Why is this?

```
// some image processing functions, e.g.
var f1 = function(image){
  var mask = image.select('B4').gt(3000)
  return image.addBands(mask.rename('m1'))
}
var f2 = function(image){
  var mask = image.select('B3').gt(3000)
  return image.addBands(mask.rename('m2'))
}

// more masking functions, etc

var myS2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR').limit(10000)
```

### **1) `map` each function**

```
var multiMaps = myS2
  .map(f1)
  .map(f2)
  .map(f3)
  .map(f4)
  .map(f5)
print(multiMaps)
```

[image]

### **2) Single `map`**

```
var perImage = myS2.map(function(image){
  image = f1(image)
  image = f2(image)
  image = f3(image)
  image = f4(image)
  image = f5(image)
  return image
})
print(perImage)
```

[image]

#### **Image.addBands in 2 takes twice as long as that of 1--why?**

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fcaseyengstrom%2Freprex%3AmultiMapFunction

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that this doesn't show an actual speed difference, but just random variation. Try running the script many times, and you'll see timings in a similar range for both versions.

This is a general fact of “benchmarking” computer programs: unless you're running them on a computer that is physically dedicated to running that program and has *nothing else going on* — no other processes, and no external inputs needing to be handled — you will see variation, and it is necessary to measure many runs over at least a few seconds of compute time to get a meaningful measurement.

Also, in Earth Engine in particular, each time your script sends a request for something to be computed (here via `print()`), it's randomly assigned to some computer running the Earth Engine software, which is also handling many other people's compute requests and other things. The time taken will depend on this unrelated load on that particular machine.

The compute time figures the Earth Engine profiler presents are *somewhat* insulated from this — they try to measure CPU cycles rather than real time passing — but there will still be influences from other work.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I should have included more images-- I increased the collection size, and found that solution #2 takes about twice as long as #1 after running each version three times. Good to know about how the profiler works though.

Comment: @cengstro If there is a stable large difference, it might be worth filing a bug report about this — `.map()`s in sequence ought to be nearly identical to a single `.map()` with a more complex function, and if they aren't, that suggests there might be an easy opportunity for making it faster. (I'm not observing as large a difference as you describe, though.)

Answer (score 0):

Kevin is correct that normally a sequence of mapping of n functions should be similar in performance to a mapping of a sequence of n functions. But gee sets up all functions in a directed acyclic graph that is then decomposed into functions that can run asynchrously and those that may have to wait for another fn. the limit is that gee cannot predict the outcome of a fn before it runs. So in option 1 gee knows each fn is adding a new band with no interaction with the other fn. this can and will be done asynchronously.  But the fn in option 2 returns a whole image. Gee does not seem to go into if the returned image requires dependencies between bands. In theory it could but it would mean evaluating masks which can vary by band.  I feel the graph simplification draws the line at such evaluations.